# glUniform - so many to choose from

Tags: opengl, shader

I've written a Shader Program wrapper for my graphics library and for completeness I wanted to give it an interface for setting uniforms.  At the moment I've got dozens of overloads as there are dozens (over two dozen just in case I'm accused of exaggerating for dramatic effect) glUniform overloads.

Have I missed the glUniform method for [uniform location], [source type], [dest type], [length], [pointer] that would enable me to compact all of this down?  I can't seem to see one.  I can splat an entire uniform buffer with one call but shader programs seems to be unnecessarily (?) fussy.

Comment: In my wrapper, I just use only the calls taking pointers with overloads. My implementation, using templates, is at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~james-gangur/sqee/trunk/view/head:/include/sqee/gl/Shaders.hpp and http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~james-gangur/sqee/trunk/view/head:/src/sqee/gl/Shaders.cpp. You probably don't need to use macros like I did in the cpp file, but yeah.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've ended up doing actually.  Still, one call would be better.